# msgOpen:unable to open message file:PROMSGS

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Hello All,

I have installed App builder 10.2B on my machine(Windows 10/64bit) for the first time. I am getting this error message when I open the app builder. I am new to progress.

Could you please take me to solve this problem step by step?. I would appreciate that.
[image]

Comment: This usually indicates an error with the startup parameters. Often a missing .ini file or a problem with the DLC environment variable. 
There are a lot of solutions to these sorts of errors in the Knowledgebase.
This isn't really the forum for this sort of question though as it's a support question, not a programming question.

Comment: OpenEdge 10.2b was released in December of 2009.  Are you installing it on an operating system of similar vintage?  If not you may also be experiencing platform incompatibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the link https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/Client-is-not-starting-error-1247-with-errno-2 and do the setup in the environmental variable.

The issue will be gone.